# How to keep the data bindings of the bindingNavigator after the dataGridView rows is filtered?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview

Senario:

(This is the original binding source of these controls)

```
itemsBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.itemsBindingSource;

itemsDataGridView.DataSource = this.itemsBindingSource;
```

But, when the itemsDataGridView rows are filtered the itemsBindingNavigator is no longer connected/binded to the itemsDataGridView when I select an specific row or a cell.

how to fix this?

Thanks in advance..

Here is the method for filter:

```
private void searchNow()
    {
        try
        {
            string rowFilter = string.Format("CONVERT(Item_Id, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'" +
            " OR CONVERT(Item, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'" +
            " OR CONVERT(Price, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'" +
            " OR CONVERT(Unit, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'" +
            " OR CONVERT(Category, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'", searchBox.Text);
            this.bakeryDatabaseDataSet.Items.DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
            itemsDataGridView.DataSource = this.bakeryDatabaseDataSet.Items;
            itemsBindingNavigator.BindingSource.DataSource = this.bakeryDatabaseDataSet.Items;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really simply answer this with the information you gave, because *we dont have the filter method*; Anyhow, the unbinding has logic behind it. the reason the navigator unbinds is because the table has changed, and the content is not the same - so the information in the cells changed, and the old navigated cells are useless. The solution is to rebind it with the old information through the filter (modify `bindingSource1` to fit the filter and `DataBind()`).

Comment: Thank you for you response A. Abramov. I have provided the filter method. Please help I'm working on my thesis.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!! :) and it worked! Thank you for the tip! What I did is...

```
private void searchNow()
    {
        try
        {
            string rowFilter = string.Format("CONVERT(Item_Id, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'" +
            " OR CONVERT(Item, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'" +
            " OR CONVERT(Price, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'" +
            " OR CONVERT(Unit, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'" +
            " OR CONVERT(Category, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'", searchBox.Text);
            this.bakeryDatabaseDataSet.Items.DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
            this.itemsBindingSource.DataSource = this.bakeryDatabaseDataSet.Items;
            itemsBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.itemsBindingSource;
            itemsDataGridView.DataSource = this.itemsBindingSource;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```